# A value of type X cannot be used to initialize an entity of type X

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
struct Value {
    struct Array;
    struct Dict;
    struct Primitive;

    Value() {}
    virtual ~Value() {}

    virtual Array * asArray() { assert(false); }
    virtual Dict * asDict() { assert(false); }
    virtual Primitive * asPrimitive() { assert(false); }

    int asInt();
    double asDouble();
    std::string asDate();
    std::string asString();
};

struct Value::Array : public Value {
    std::vector<Value> m_data;

    Array() {}
    ~Array() {}

    Value::Array * asArray() { 
        Value::Array * result = this; 
        return result;
    }
};
```

The statement `Value::Array * result = this;` is giving me this error...

`E0144  a value of type "Value::Array *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "Value::Array *".`

Comment: Ahha.  I thought you were calling me stupid before the edit.  Does that mean I can ignore it and my code will still compile?

Comment: I'm staring at this but I don't realize what's wrong with the C++ code. Concerning the compiler, over the years I saw such things from time to time. (My personal favorite is: "bool is not compatible with bool") It seems that even compiler constructors make mistakes... :-)

Comment: Yes, this code should work fine. The thing is intellisense uses its own fancy parser so intellisense errors often do not correlate with compiler errors.

Comment: **There is no issue with code.** We should always be able to differentiate between compiler/linker error and IDE related errors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be seen in much simpler code

```
enum SPELLSTATUS { NEW, FAIL, OK } spellStatus = SPELLSTATUS::NEW;
```

or

```
enum SPELLSTATUS { NEW, FAIL, OK } spellStatus = NEW;

E0144   a value of type "SPELLSTATUS" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "SPELLSTATUS"  NcEdit  D:\Systems\Editor2019\Spell.cpp 30  

VS2019.
```

Compiles and runs just fine.

Comment: Please edit your answer to put the code in code format.